# Horizontal barplot in ggplot2 with faces having different categories

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

I have a data frame with ids, categories, and values, while I manage easily to have an horizontal dot-plot, with products grouped by category in distinct facets,
when I try with a barplot, event categories with missing data show up.

Any hint? Is it a bug or am I missing some detail?

Thanks,
Marco.

```
## I have a data frame with ids, categories, and values
d=data.frame(prd=c("orange","apple","pear","bread","crackers"),
         cat=c("fruit","fruit","fruit","bakery","bakery"),
         qty=c(10,20,15,8,17)
         )

# I manage to have an horizontal dot-plot, with products grouped by category in distinct facets
ggplot(d,aes(y=prd,x=qty)) + 
  geom_point(stat="identity",size=4) + 
  geom_segment(aes(yend=prd), xend=0, colour="grey50") +
  facet_grid(cat ~ .,scale="free",space="free") +
  theme_light()

# though when I try with a barplot, bars, with missing data show up
ggplot(d,aes(x=prd,y=qty)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_grid(cat ~ .,scale="free",space="free") +
  theme_light()
```

Comment: This issue has been raised several times before on SO, see e.g. among [**these posts**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+coord_flip+free) and on [**ggplot github**](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/95).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ggplot2 does not currently support free scales with a non-cartesian coord or coord_flip.

So either you could plot them without flip:

```
ggplot(d,aes(y=qty,x=prd)) + 
facet_wrap(~cat, scale="free") +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
theme_light()
```

Or you flip but use a workaround, for ex. make one categorical variable out of two (I admit that this solution is not very visually appealing):

```
d$n <- paste(d$cat, d$prd, sep="|")

ggplot(d,aes(y=qty,x=n)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
coord_flip() +
theme_light()
```